# how do i execute a command at an entity with a certain nbt data

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to execute a test command where every single creeper with a walkspeed of 0 spawned in runs a command to summon a zombie directly at the creeper with the NBT data I specified.

Commands I tried:

- `/execute as @e[type=creeper] at @s[nbt={Attributes:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0f}] run summon zombie`
- `/execute at @e[type=creeper,nbt={Attributes:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0f}] run summon zombie`
- `/execute at @e[type=creeper] if entity @s[nbt={Attributes:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0f}] run summon zombie`

Those commands did not work, how do I do this?

Comment: What do those commands do? Error message, blow up your house, speak insults?

Answer (score 2):

Your NBT data is malformed. You have to provide a list of attributes, even if you only want to specify one, and for each attribute you want to specify you have to give its name and base value.

- You start constructing your NBT data with your attribute, which is a compound. Compounds are marked as `{...}`.
- An attribute needs two elements, its `Name` and `Base`.
- Each element has a value and you construct an element with a value with `element:value`. So in this case you do `Name:"generic.movementSpeed"` and `Base:0d`. You put the `generic.movementSpeed` in quotation marks, because it is of type String (computer talk for text) and you put the `d` behind the number because it is of type Double (computer talk for a decimal number).
- To put several elements (with values) inside a compound you separate them with a comma.

Overall you get:

```
{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:0d}
```

Now that you have your attribute you have to consider that Minecraft expects an element called `Attributes` with a value that is a list of all attributes. You create a list with `[...]`. Put your attribute compound into it to form a list with one element (which is your attribute compound, which itself has two elements), so you just surround your attribute with `[...]`. Now put this as the value of the element `Attributes`:

```
Attributes:[{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:0d}]
```

When checking with `nbt=...` Minecraft always expects a single NBT compound, so add another `{...}` around this. If you want to check any creeper for this you can do:

```
\execute as @e[type=creeper,nbt={Attributes:[{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:0d}]}] run ...
```

Or you do it split up into an `as` and an `at` like you did in your first command. The second and third commands you specified would not work as expected, because you never specify an `as`, thus the command will check the currently executing entity whether it is a creeper with the NBT attribute. And this is normally the player who runs the command.

For doing something (like summoning a zombie) at the position of those creepers replace the `run ...` with `at @s run ...`.

HOWEVER, note that this will check for creepers that have this movement speed attribute, NOT for creepers that *are currently moving with this speed*. So to check for any still standing creepers this won't work.